# Как создать правильный sql запрос

Tags: postgresql, join, alias

Есть две таблицы нужно составить запросы -  Написать запрос, который выводит количество всех продуктов определенного типа.

6. Написать запрос получение всех продуктов с типом "СЫР" и "МОЛОКО"
7. Написать запрос, который выводит тип продуктов, которых осталось меньше 10 штук.

Я создал такой запрос для варианта номер 6 -

select s.name, ss.name from product as s join type ss on s.type_id = ss.id where ss.name = 'Молоко' and  ss.name = 'Сыр' group by ss.name; но там ошибка

```
create table type(
                     id serial primary key,
                     name varchar(20)
);

create table product (
    id serial primary key,
    name varchar(20),
    expired_date date,
    price int,
    type_id int references type(id)
);

insert into type(name) values ('Сыр');
insert into type(name) values ('Молоко');
insert into type(name) values ('Творог');
insert into type(name) values ('Мороженное');

insert into product(name, expired_date, price, type_id) values ('Французский', '2021-04-10', 250, 1);
insert into product(name, expired_date, price, type_id) values ('Фермерский', '2021-05-13', 2500, 1);
insert into product(name, expired_date, price, type_id) values ('Плавленный', '2021-06-13', 200, 1);

insert into product(name, expired_date, price, type_id) values ('Домашнее', '2021-04-03', 50, 2);
insert into product(name, expired_date, price, type_id) values ('Пастеризованное', '2021-10-13', 100, 2);
insert into product(name, expired_date, price, type_id) values ('Веселый Молочник', '2021-03-23', 75, 2);
insert into product(name, expired_date, price, type_id) values ('Любительское', '2021-04-03', 60, 2);

insert into product(name, expired_date, price, type_id) values ('Домашний', '2021-03-15', 300, 3);
insert into product(name, expired_date, price, type_id) values ('Бабушкин', '2021-03-17', 320, 3);

insert into product(name, expired_date, price, type_id) values ('Пломбир мороженное', '2021-05-13', 50, 4);
insert into product(name, expired_date, price, type_id) values ('Сникерс мороженное', '2021-04-13', 55, 4);
insert into product(name, expired_date, price, type_id) values ('Просто мороженное', '2021-03-13', 60, 4);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первый запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM `product` LEFT JOIN `type` on `product`.`type_id` = `type`.`id` WHERE `type`.`name` = 'Сыр' OR `type`.`name` = 'Молоко';
```

Вы допустили ошибку в выборе типов. у Вас выбираются товары с одновременными типами "Молоко" И "Сыр", чего по факту быть не может (даже потому что связь типа один к одному).

---

Второй запрос:

```
SELECT `type`.`name`, COUNT(`product`.`name`) as `count` FROM `type` RIGHT JOIN `product` ON `product`.`type_id` = `type`.`id` GROUP BY `type`.`name` HAVING COUNT(`product`.`name`) < 3
```

Здесь нужно группировать предметы по типам, а потом через `HAVING` отсекать лишние данные. Вывел товары, количество которых меньше трёх, чтобы показать, что это будет работать на Ваших предоставленных данных.

Comment: а если не трудно как написать такой запрос  - Написать запрос, который выводит количество всех продуктов определенного типа.

Comment: @Terasan В первом убрать `OR `type`.`name` = 'Молоко'` - будет выводить все товары одного типа, который укажете

Comment: Спасибо ) подскажите книга  евгения моргунова основы языка нормальная как самоучитель?